# VueJS Rollup export multiple scss resources

Tags: vue.js, rollupjs, postcss

Is it possible to export multiple (s)css resources using Rollup for Vue?
What I want to accomplish is:

- **components.scss** extracted `<style lang="scss">` from src/components/**/*.vue (including @import files).
- **components.css** parsed components.scss with tailwindcss and autoprefixer.
- **theme.scss** default generic theme styling (buttons, etc)
- **theme.css** parsed theme.scss with tailwindcss and autoprefixer

So far I have managed to get dist/components.scss bundled using rollup-plugin-bundle-scss but I am not sure how to add the other files. If I import theme.scss in my index.js entry file, it is added to the bundle also, which is not what I want. I could expose src/assets/theme.scss in the package.json but I still need a parsed version

If there is a way to copy components.scss before bundling, than that would also be a good option.

Part of my rollup.config.js

```
 plugins: [      
  bundleScss({output: 'components.scss', exclusive: false }),
  scss(),
  postcss(),
  resolve({ extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue'] }),
  vue( { css: true })
 ]
```

postcss.config.js

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    tailwindcss,
    autoprefixer,
  ],
};
```

Any thought on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I just rubberducked myself. After posting this I noticed an example config with multiple export entries so I added a config entry with theme.scss as input. The output is like expected.

1 thing I don't like is that the build process triggers a warning

> The emitted file "theme.css" overwrites a previously emitted file of
> the same name.

Meaning the output is written twice, I don't know why that happens or if it can be ignored.

```
const cssOnlyConfig = {
  input: 'src/assets/theme.scss',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/theme.css',
    format: 'es',
    exports: 'default'
  },
  plugins: [
    postcss({
      modules: false,
      extract: true
    }),
    vue({
      css:true,
    }),
  ],
};
```